# NameError with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel

*#hello guys, I can't load or work with excel sheets, can someone help?*

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('exel.xlsx')
sheet = wb['oo']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)
print(cell.value)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cell' is not defined
```

*#this is my first time posting on stack overflow so sorry if my question is a mess and not organized*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have openpyxl installed in your environment:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

or if you're on unix:

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

then try again.  Please also check if that's your only error message or if you are only seeing the last message.

Comment: thank you, that solved it. i installed it in a deferent environment